# How to implement Algolia in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, algolia

I am trying to implement Algolia search in unity, everything working fine in the editor but things break in standalone build (windows). it gives the following error

```
Unable to find a constructor to use for type 
Algolia.Search.Models.Search.SearchResponse`1[AlgoliaTileResults]. A class should either have a 
default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor 
attribute. Path 'hits', line 1,
```

This is how my AlgoliaTileResults class looks

```
public class AlgoliaTileResults
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public AlgoliaTileResults(int ID)
    {
        id = ID;
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I am using algoila

```
results = await _algoliaIndex.SearchAsync<AlgoliaTileResults>(new Query(searchQuery)
        {
            HitsPerPage = _ALGOLIAHITSPERPAGE,
            Page = currentpage
        });
```

I have also used this version of newtonsoft json https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity

Comment: A vague shot in the dark .. but maybe this is related somehow to code stripping? Maybe the constructor is never explicitly used so the compiler thinks it can just remove it? This often happens when things are only used via reflection or stuff like the `Activator` .. Maybe try to explicitly omit [Unity code stripping](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html) for this file or use the [`[Preserve]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Scripting.PreserveAttribute.html) attribute

Comment: yeah, disabling code stripping is not possible for me as am using IL2CPP but I did set it to low and used the Preserve keyword. but still the same problem.